# biopython-motifs , How can I create motif from sequences of different length?

Tags: python, motifs

I want to create motif of different length kmers.
Following code works for kmers of same length but not different length.What to do ?

```py
from Bio import motifs

sequences = SeqIO.parse("myfile.fasta","fasta")
    instances = []
    for data in sequences:
      instance = data.seq
      instances.append(instance)
    
motif = motifs.create(instances)
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit @finswimmer

Answer (score 3):

Motifs are not designed to be variable length in general since PSSMs/PVMs don't support insertions/deletions (indels). Instead, I suggest profile HMMs, such as those offered by HMMER3, which do support indels. You can parse HMMER3 output with Biopython via `Bio.SearchIO.HmmerIO`

Answer (score 1):

All sequences represented in a [Biopython motif object](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.motifs.html) must be the same length. For example, a motif has a `__len__` property, which has to consist of a single value.

There are [other methods](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-38746-w) that *do* support variable-length motifs, I suggest that you look into them, but unfortunately biopython seems to be limited to fixed-length motifs.